# Magic Leap Menu UI disappear

Tags: spatial, magic-leap

Im using [Magic Leap One: Creator Edition](https://www.magicleap.com/magic-leap-one) almost everyday for Unity Development, but I stumbled across the following issue:

Magic Leap does not show anything (Menu and icons) when I start magic Leap device. I see the starting screen with and astronaut flying with text *TAP TO START*. I click, as usual, and it takes around 30-45 seconds to load and everything disappears (No UI/UX of Menu with app icons). Sometimes I get pop up message *Scan Area* and when I scan it popups with *Area Recognized* and still nothing happens after scanning. Even after closing all applications and restarting the device, the same issue arises.

What could be the cause? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake I made. I changed the models for Icon and Portal with unsupported high polygon models from asset store. If you want to avoid this trouble, follow guidelines for icon and portal asset development.